# Line graph in ASP.NET using Datasource

Tags: asp.net

I am somewhat a beginner in ASP.NET (C#), and I would like to know if it is feasible to draw a line chart of a time-series using data from a SQL table (SQL Server).

I haven't found any control that allows for a drawing of a time-series (i.e. Time as X-axis variable).

Also, I would like for the user to be able to hover over the chart and see data, as demonstrated in the following link:

[link](http://demos.devexpress.com/xtrachartsdemos/PointAndLineViewTypes/LineSeries.aspx)

Could anyone please enlighten me as to what is the best way to achieve such a result?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You have quite a few options, [Reporting Services](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159106.aspx) provides all sorts of graph and charting mechanisms. A personal favourite of mine is [JQPlot](http://www.jqplot.com/index.php). The bonus of the latter is that it's free!

Comment: I'd add that SSRS, while powerful, can require a lot of setting up to get it working right - especially in a website.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was hinting at... there's the MS way then there's the easy way!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the Microsoft Chart controls.

have a look at ScottGU Blog [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/11/24/new-asp-net-charting-control-lt-asp-chart-runat-quot-server-quot-gt.aspx)

I have used it and it works really well.  The best part is that itès free ;)

HTH

Comment: It looks promising! Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: I do recommend to download the ASP.NET Samples project.